# create vscode tree item extesion

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, typescript, async-await

I use the following code to add tree item to vscode extension, Im getting the data and build the tree according to the entries I got, the code works. 
As I new to typescript I appreciate your feedback's, if the code looks good let me know either :) thanks

````
export class TaskTreeDataProvider implements vscode.TreeDataProvider<TreeItem> {

private _onDidChangeTreeData: vscode.EventEmitter<TreeItem | null> = new vscode.EventEmitter<TreeItem | null>();
  readonly onDidChangeTreeData: vscode.Event<TreeItem | null> = this
    ._onDidChangeTreeData.event;

  private eeake: Promise<TreeItem[]> | undefined = undefined;
  private autoRefresh: boolean = true;

  constructor(private context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    this.autoRefresh = vscode.workspace
      .getConfiguration(“sView")
      .get("autorefresh");

    let filePath = this.fileName;
    let fileWatcher = vscode.workspace.createFileSystemWatcher(filePath);
    fileWatcher.onDidChange(() => (this.eeake = this.getChildren()), this.refresh());
  }

  refresh(): void {
    this._onDidChangeTreeData.fire();
  }

  public async getChildren(task?: TreeItem): Promise<TreeItem[]> {
    let tasks = await vscode.tasks
      .fetchTasks({ type: “run” })
      .then(function (value) {
        return value;
      });

    let entry: TreeItem[] = [];
    if (tasks.length !== 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
        entry[i] = new TreeItem(
          tasks[i].definition.type,
          tasks[i].name,
          {
            command: “sView.executeTask",
            title: "Execute",
            arguments: [tasks[i]]
          }
        );
      }
    }
    return entry;
  }

  getTreeItem(task: TreeItem): vscode.TreeItem {
    return task;
  }
}



class TreeItem extends vscode.TreeItem {
  type: string;
  constructor(
    type: string,
    label: string,
    collapsibleState: vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState,
    command?: vscode.Command
  ) {
    super(label, collapsibleState);
    this.type = type;
    this.command = command;
    this.iconPath = getIcon();
  }
```
````

Comment: Why use `let` when you are not changing the variable. Every linter will tell you that.